# SQL - Return data from two differnt tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables BOOKINGS and WORKERS. Basically there is table for a worker, and a table to keep track of what a worker has to do in a time frame aka (BOOKINGS). For example Jeff belongs to the WORKERS table, and in the BOOKING table Jeff is working from 2016-11-10 to 2016-11-15.

I’m trying to check if there is an available worker for a job. Say I need something done from 2016-11-11 to 2016-11-14. I need to be able to see if there is a worker who is not booked at that time, and display all the workers that are available for that job. 
So I query the booking to check if requested time has available workers between the start end date.

However, the way I'm doing it does a join of the tables WORKERS and BOOKINGS and it only returns matching and non matching data out of BOOKINGS. For example say i have 10 workers and 4 workers workers are book at random times. My query only checks the 4 workers in BOOKINGS and disregards all the WOEKERS not yet with jobs. As you can see that is a huge problem. How do i query all the available workers as described ? Do i have to do the logic via my php script ?

Thanks everyone!!!!!! I understand this is a complex task and apperaite the time you took readings this.

Worker Table

```
CREATE TABLE WORKERS (
            ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            WORKER_NAME  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
            WORKER_CODE  INT, 
            WORKER_WAGE  INT, 
            PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Booking Table

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKINGS (
            ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            WORKER_NAME  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
            START DATE NOT NULL,
            END DATE NOT NULL,
            CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,  
            PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Client Table (Though not important)

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTS (
            ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            CLIENT_NAME  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
            ADDRESS VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
            PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Current query

```
SELECT WORKERS.ID, WORKERS.WORKER_NAME, WORKERS.WORKER_CODE, WORKERS.WORKER_WAGE 
FROM WORKERS
INNER JOIN BOOKINGS
ON WORKERS.WORKER_NAME = BOOKINGS.WORKER_NAME
WHERE (START NOT BETWEEN :start AND :end)
ORDER BY WORKERS.ID
```

PHP Statement

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$bname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT WORKERS.ID, WORKERS.WORKER_NAME, WORKERS.WORKER_CODE, WORKERS.WORKER_WAGE 
FROM WORKERS
INNER JOIN BOOKINGS
ON WORKERS.WORKER_NAME = BOOKINGS.WORKER_NAME
WHERE (START NOT BETWEEN :start AND :end)
ORDER BY WORKERS.ID
");
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$workers = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Examples
[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all available workers with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM WORKERS AS w
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1
    FROM BOOKINGS 
    WHERE START BETWEEN :start AND :end
      AND WORKER_NAME = w.WORKER_NAME
)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of ' select 1'  ?

Comment: Because you have to select something, but what you select is not important in this case. The only thing that counts is whether the subquery returns at least one row or not.

Answer (score 3):

You could select all workers that are not in the list of workers busy at given time slot.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM WORKERS
WHERE WORKER_NAME NOT IN ( 
    SELECT WORKER_NAME
    FROM BOOKINGS 
    WHERE START BETWEEN :start AND :end
)
```

Comment: It's better not to use `NOT IN` in this case. See https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Why not use NOT BETWEEN

Comment: The sub-query selects all workers from bookings that are busy, before all workers that are not busy were selected.

Comment: Because you want to know if there is an available worker at this period. Not if there is a worker that worked outside of this period.

Comment: While this query does display the correct output, @lovasoa has a point about NOT IN. Ill select him for answer, but you still deserve points and i appreciate your help.